# python dict: how to assign a value to a key which will raise an error if it is accessed though the key as a one-liner?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, error-handling

What I'm looking for is to define a dict and assign initial values to keys. Furthermore, I want to define certain keys as errors, and I want these errors to be raised immediately if the key is used. E.g.

```
d = {}
d["foo"] = "bar"
d["baz"] = "rat"
d["no-no"] = raise ValueError("This is a no-no") # this is invalid syntax, but should clarify what I'm looking for.
```

such that when somebody would call

```
>>> d["foo"]
bar
>>> d["baz"]
rat
>>> d["no-no"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: This is a no-no
```

Is it possible to do this as a one-liner? Only other solution I can think of is to create a subclass of `dict` and overwrite the setter function, but I'd like to avoid that, and solve it as a one-liner instead.

Comment: I don't think you have another choice than to create a subclass of `dict` to achieve this (efficiently).

Comment: do you know all the valid keys ahead of time, or the dict still needs to accept arbitrary unknown keys in addition to the forbidden ones and the ones with default values?

Comment: @Anentropic I know all the valid and invalid keys ahead of time.

Comment: You want the error to be raised only upon access?

Comment: @user2390182 yes, I want the error to be raised only upon access.

Comment: hm.. seems unlikely to be possibe. Whatever is bound to a key is an object that you'll be able to be accesse. Raising the error is a functionality that needs to be triggered somehow. That requires some extra call to a function or the like

Comment: I was hoping there was some mechanism similar to @property to modify the access behaviour or some such.

Comment: Nah, the access is the sole business of the `dict`. The contained object does not know about itself being stored to or retrieved from a collection. The same is not true for attributes though. The "descriptor" protocol allows you to trigger any behaviour when an attribute is accessed.

Comment: The best I was able to to was subclass dict and overriding the __getitem__ method so that, if you define `d["no-no"] = ValueError("This is a no-no")`, this error will be raised when accessing the key.

Comment: the answer probably disappeared because I explicitly asked for a way which doesn't involve creating a subclass.

Comment: @Gameplay Both answers were deleted by their authors because they didn't provide an acceptable solution.

Comment: Counter question then, @mivkov how would you imagine an implementation which doesn't involve a subclass and would give a built-in type a behaviour it doesn't have (doc for ref https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)? Don't get me wrong, but it seems to be a X-Y question. Is there a rationale behind it being a one-liner?

Comment: @Gameplay as I wrote in a previous comment, something along the lines of an `@property` decorator which would modify the default behaviour of specific getter method perhaps.

Comment: But to which method in which class would you apply such decorator?

Comment: Look, if I had all the answers, I wouldn't have posted the question in the first place, would I? I just figured there might be a way to do it, as I didn't see anything in principle that would prohibit it.

Comment: @mivkov if you know all the valid and invalid keys ahead of time then I think it would make more sense to use a class (e.g. dataclass) instead of a dict. A dataclass will make it easy to define default initial values and you can add `@property` implementations raising error for disallowed keys. Additionally have a look at [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/) which builds on dataclasses to give additional tools for validating values and converting to/from raw dictionaries.